# ui-li-aside text-overlapping text-overflow jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, overflow, word-wrap, ellipsis

In Jquery mobile : How to  stop over-flow of text in listview while using class ui-li-aside .
Tried all type of position which includes relative,static,absolute . I want text not to overflow but to wrap up with ellipsis

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the  way  to add ellipsis is to add table .below is the sample code

```
<li>
<a href="#pcontent?id=100" >
<table width="75%" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr width="100%">
        <td style="display:block;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:no-wrap">
            1. Indian Combo - Vegetarian</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</a>
<p class="ui-li-aside" style="top:0.98em;font-size:16px;"><strong>$10.95</strong></p>
</li>
```

Sample image attached  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MboN8.png